# Connecting 2 points in a map using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have the following code to plot 2 points in ggmap

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(lat=c(12.97131,12.98692),
        lon=c(77.5121,77.68627))

Bangalore <- get_map("Bangalore,India", zoom=12)

p <- ggmap(Bangalore)
p + geom_point(data=d, aes(x=lon, y=lat),color="red",size=3)

ggplot(p)
```

These points are showing as red dots in the map. How can I connect these points?

Comment: Try using `geom_line()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for the final `ggplot(p)` (that's probably throwing an error on your end) and I'd use `geom_path`:

```
p <- ggmap(Bangalore)
p <- p + geom_point(data=d, aes(x=lon, y=lat),color="red",size=3)
p + geom_path(data=d, aes(x=lon, y=lat), color="black", size=1)
## or....
p + geom_line(data=d, aes(x=lon, y=lat), color="black", size=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm _kinda_ ok with suggesting `geom_line`, but it's been my experience dealing with mapping that folks generally want to plot lines between points in the order that they appear vs by the ordered values of `x`. I, perhaps, extrapolated too much from the OP (I figured they were going to plot more lines - i.e. draw a path between many points).