# how to plot multiple path on map using ggplot2 and ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, geospatial, ggmap

I need to plot multiple path on map. whether two locations are connected are indicated by group

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(lat=c(12.97131,12.98692,12.90692,12.78692,,12.70692),
    lon=c(77.5121,77.68627, 76.5121, 78.5121,78.05121),
    group=c(1,1,2,2,2))

Bangalore <- get_map("Bangalore,India", zoom=12)

p <- ggmap(Bangalore)
```

However I don't know how to use geom_path or other command to draw them

```
p + geom_path(data=d, aes(x=lon, y=lat), color="black", size=1)
```

I've referring to this earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572663/connecting-2-points-in-a-map-using-ggplot) which draws one line between two points, yet i need to draw lines between multiple groups of points. how can i do so?

Answer (score 1):

Use `aes(group=xxx)`:

```
Bangalore <- get_map("Bangalore,India", zoom=8)
p <- ggmap(Bangalore)
p + geom_path(data=d, aes(x=lon, y=lat, group=group), color="black", size=1)
```

By the way, the zoom level `12` is too high to display group 2's data, unzoom to level `8` to see your example data.

Comment: thanks @Blacksad. Is using lon & lat the only way to plot path on map? is there a way to use global city-names?

Comment: You can use `ggmap`function `geocode()` (e.g. `geocode("paris")`) to get cities's lat/lon from city's name.

Comment: it works great for continents. thanks so much. actually just realise get_map() doesn't support world map. how should i draw path on world map?

Comment: This might help: [R Beginners – Plotting Locations on to a World Map](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-beginners-plotting-locations-on-to-a-world-map/)